# Returning wrong results in perl script

Tags: linux, scripting, perl

I am running this command on linux shell it works smoothly

`sed -i 's/\[-.*-]//g' error .txt`

What it does is it removes patterns like [-any text-] along with the brackets and - sign.

but when I try to run it through perl script , it removes only '-' sign.

I tried to use 
`system("sed -i 's/\[-.*-]//g' error.txt");`

Please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is it duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use double quotes for the string in perl, the `\` in the string gets interpreted by perl.

Use a double backslash, i.e. `system("sed -i 's/\\[-.*-]//g' error.txt");`

Or use `[[]` instead of `\[`, i.e. `system("sed -i 's/[[]-.*-]//g' error.txt");`
This variant will work in the shell as well.

Comment: Thanks for this similarly will this  `system("sed -i 's/[{}+.*+]//g' error.txt");` remove this {+anytext+} ?

Comment: @Coolstrike No. The pattern `[{}+.*+]` matches any character between the brackets, i.e. one of `{`, `}`, `+`, `.`, `*`. The trailing `/g` makes `sed` replace all occurrences. Use `s/{[+].*[+]}//g`

Comment: Hi, if I only want to remove [- and -] will this work ? `sed -i  's/[-//' file.txt`

Comment: @Coolstrike Please don't add more variants of your question in comments. You should edit your question instead or write a new question. To make your additional question I suggest to add an example of the input text and the expected output. If you want to know if your proposed command works, you can simply try it. (It will not work.)

Answer (score 0):

backslash inside a double quoted string in perl is interpreted by the perl, so the command that is being run is

```
 sed -i 's/[-.*-]//g' error.txt
```

and this will remove minus, dot and asterisk characters. The fact that you list minus a second time doesn't worry sed.

perl has a number of quoting tools, in particular you can use the `q` operator so

```
 system(q(sed -i 's/\[-.*-]//g' error.txt));
```

would work. See `man perlop`